# Convert text into R date class in UTF-16 files before and after excel opening?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app that requires an input cvs (UTF-16) file which gets downloaded from a system. Depending on whether the user uploads the file directly from their download folder on their local machine OR the user opens the file in excel, saves it on their local machine, and uploads it to shiny, it uploads different date field format.

In order to give a robust solution to this user problem, I tried the following customized function:

```
 .asDate <- function(x) {
    if(nchar(x) < 20) {
      as.POSIXct(strptime(x, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M"))
    } else {
      as.POSIXct(strptime(x, "%b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p"))
    }
  }
```

But, when I actually sapply against the column, I get a numeric output:

```
 foo <- data.frame(start.time = c("2012/02/06 15:47", 
                                   "2012/02/06 15:02",
                                   "2012/02/22 10:08"),
                    duration   = c(1,2,3),
                    stringsAsFactors = F)
 sapply(foo$start.time, .asDate)

2012/02/06 15:47 2012/02/06 15:02 2012/02/22 10:08 
         1.3e+09          1.3e+09          1.3e+09
```

Instead of the correct conversion I'm looking for:

```
 as.POSIXct(strptime(foo$start.time, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M"))

[1] "2012-02-06 15:47:00 EST" "2012-02-06 15:02:00 EST" "2012-02-22 10:08:00 EST"
```

Could someone help with correcting this issue?

Answer (score 1):

`sapply` returns a vector and is converting your dates into numeric class. I just tried using lapply and it returned the output that you were looking for:

```
lapply(foo$start.time, .asDate)
```

Or you can just use the function you created:

```
yourDates<-.asDate(foo$start.time)
```

If you are really keen on using sapply you could do the following(which is the same as lapply):

```
sapply(foo$start.time, .asDate, simplify = F, USE.NAMES = F)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However when I try to convert the list into a vector by doing do.call(rbind, lapply(foo$start.time, .asDate)), it happens again. If I need to convert the date field and keep it in a data frame class, how would you recommend I go about doing so?

Comment: It seems like the dates are getting converted back to numeric when you `unlist` the list. You could just create a data frame and use your function instead of using lapply. `dateData<-data.frame(Dates = .asDate(foo$start.time)` Mind you that the condition in your function only checks the first element of your vector, so you might need to change that up if you want it to check each element of the vector.

Comment: To fix the condition issue, wrap your condition with the `any` function. `if(any(nchar(x) < 20)) {
      as.POSIXct(strptime(x, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M"))
    }`

Comment: I just noticed that the "EST" gets dropped when you create the data frame. If you still want that, you can add this: `dateData[,1] = paste(dateData[,1], "EST")`

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why the .asDate function isn't just simply working? I'd love to understand why it requires a round about way of converting the vector into as Date class..

Comment: What do you mean your `.asDate` function isn't working? When I ran it, it returned a vector with the output you wanted. As for the time zone getting cut off, it looks like when you create a `data frame`, string columns get automatically converted to `factor` class, so the conversion chops off the time zone. I am not too sure about why that is, but my guess is is that the time zone part of the string is apart of another class, `POSIXt` and it's incompatible with the factor conversion. When you check the class of `yourDates` you get `POSIXct POSIXt`. The former is your date/time.

Comment: Btw, here is a one line way to create the dates data frame: `dateData<-data.frame(Dates = paste(yourDates, Sys.timezone(location = F)))
`

Comment: What I mean by the function 'not working' is that the approach of creating separate data frame and pasting time zone forces the class to be either text or factor depending on stringAsFactors condition. But my intention is to turn the field into a date field so that the system recognizes that field in graph visual. Any idea how I can keep it as a date field?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the dates column of the data frame with `I()`? That tells R to treat the object AsIs, which means that the data frame won't change the class type of your dates to `factor`.